# WindowBuilder: change language at runtime

Tags: java, localization, internationalization, resourcebundle, windowbuilder

So I have this Java project (JDesktopPane with JInternalFrames) with WindowBuilder and now I am to translate the whole program. Every time a JInternalFrame is opened from the JDesktopPane Menu, a new JInternalFrame will be instanciated.

Task: the user should be able to switch between various languages at runtime (the language must not change directly, it would be sufficient on re-opening the JInternalFrame. Right now I make use of the ResourceBundle in every JInternalFrame:

```
private static ResourceBundle BUNDLE;
```

An set the text with:

```
lblText = new JLabel(BUNDLE.getString("TestWindow.lblText.text")); //$NON-NLS-1$
```

In order to switch between the languages, I have a Menu in the JDesktopPane, which sets for example

```
language = "en";
```

Upon creating a new Window, the JInternalFrame gets a reference to the MainWindow and reads this property and sets it in the JInternalFrame:

```
BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle("TestWindow.messages_"+ mainWindow.language); //$NON-NLS-1$
```

The problem: WindowBuilder interferes this and sets

```
private static final ResourceBundle BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle("TestWindow.messages"); //$NON-NLS-1$
```

every Time I open the Window in the design view. Furthermore, I get plenty of errors in the Editor Errors window of WindowBuilder which is because the Editor can't resolve `"TestWindow.messages_"+ mainWindow.language`, which is clear to me.

Is there any way of dealing with this in a more correct way? I wasn't able to figure something correct out within WindowBuilder so I came up with this hacky solution.

Thanks,
king-al

Comment: please to read [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/index.html), code [examples are here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0220__I18N/Catalog0220__I18N.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en")); // Locale.ENGLISH
```

be sufficient? Simply getting the root bundle will get the correct locale bundle.